# Mathematica 8 overflow error by Mod command (RSA-code)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, overflow, modulo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mathematica Overflow[] error : Why and how-to bypass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095416/mathematica-overflow-error-why-and-how-to-bypass)

I have to decrypt an RSA code but when I do I get an overflow error

the formule to encrypt is `Mod[x^e,m]`
the formule to decrypt is `Mod[y^g,m]`

this is my input:

```
c[x_] := Mod[x^e, m]

dc[f_] := Mod[f^g, m]
```

with these numbers:

```
a := 762848601311969474260421138011

b := 9354

g := a

e := 100003

m := 8155564322963545435233042348043
```

The two messages are issued when I use:

```
y1 := 701056613179062784283291508801 

y2 := 6001020772977398118504479017163
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit**
Fixed it, 
`Mod[x^g,m]` is the same as

`PowerMod[x,g,m]` now it works,

Comment: @GregS I think I like `SuperMod` better as a name.

Comment: @GregS you're right, little mistake